# VANET simulation

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm currently learning simulation of vehicular networks using OMNET++, I read about sumo and veins. 
I added them successfully, 
I want to simulate a pseudonym changing strategy based on the use of mix-zone at intersections for comparative study purposes.
However, I need your help in getting started. I do not know how to start, what to model and how to use veins and sumo with omnet to model the vehicles (moving) and RSU (nor how to choose the mix-zones) in the map (I'm getting the map from openstreetmap).
I would appreciate the help of those who have gone through the same experience while trying to simulate VANET.
Regards.

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

You should start with the [tictoc tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) for OMNeT and the [tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) for Veins. Then have a deeper look at the scenario which is used there to figure out which modules from Veins are involved and how they are related. Also consider the [documentation](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/) for help.

Edit: After you setup everything and had a look at the documentation, you can read [Building my own veins scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609196/building-my-own-veins-scenario/46647841#46647841) in order to understand how Veins works.

Comment: I'm at that phase, however I still cannot fully understand how to use it.

Comment: Mr. Julian I learned how to use sumo to create simulation files for an openstreet map. I created an omnet project and made it reference to veins . then I modified the veins example (I copied it to my new project) to use my map. Now I want to make the vehicle change its pseudonym every 1 min. I don't know how to do so yet, I'm still trying. your help will be appreciated

Comment: Changing a vehicle's pseudonym sounds like it belongs to application layer logic, hence you should implement the changing in the APP-Layer which in the Demo is the _Traci11pDemo_ and inherits from _BaseWaveAppLayer_.

For actual changing have a look at the _TraCIScenarioManager_.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, could you please give me a hint on how to use it.