# Building my own veins scenario

Tags: omnet++, beacon, veins

I need to build a scenario from scratch.
Two vehicles moving on a straight road. There is a single rsu.
The rsu brodcasts the speed value every 10s. Vehicles should slow down to reach that value.

My question is
can i consider the msg as a beacon? If yes, how can i set the beacon msg in the rsu application? And if no, how to implement such scenario

Comment: Could you add a little bit more context to your question? It is quite hard to answer without understanding what you want to achieve

Comment: I am just learning what is beacon and how messages are exchanged between nodes. So I imagined that scenario, The RSU keeps sending the speed value that vehicles shouldn't exceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at the following answered questions, since they are somewhat similar to your question or at least give you some insight in how messages between vehicles are handled in Veins.

Please note that you should get a basic understanding of how OMNeT++ works first. You can use the [TicToc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) to do that.

- [how to getting start to build a veins application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390016/how-to-getting-start-to-build-a-veins-application)
- [what policy is based vehicle rerouting in case of accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373278/what-policy-is-based-vehicle-rerouting-in-case-of-accident)
- [What exactly does handleParkingUpdate() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372048/what-exactly-does-handleparkingupdate-do/43430215#43430215)
- [The necessity of handleSelfMsg in BaseWaveApplLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46393212/the-necessity-of-handleselfmsg-in-basewaveappllayer)

Comment: Thanks. But i still don't know the role of beacons and what data they include.