# how to implement different congestion avoidance techniques in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

i have a graduation project with the title " congestion avoidance in VANet" , i found a good book which has a lot of congestion avoidance techniques ([link of this book](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f8b7/8133819b25413e39be65e18a20e6b5d1610a.pdf)), now i have a problem of how can i make a good algorithms of these techniques, and how can i implement at least two of them , i took a look at many veins classes like `TraCIScenarioManager` and `TraCIMobility` but i found them so complicated and i didn't know from where should i start !

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46609196/building-my-own-veins-scenario/46647841#46647841 and feel free to up-vote, if it helped you.

Comment: yes it helped me a little but i am really newbie with c++, and i would be so thankful if you could take a look on those techniques listed in the book, and help me to implement two of them on `MyVeinsApp` class , and thank you so much sir !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by doing the [TicToc tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) to learn how OMNeT++ works. You just need basic c++ knowledge.
Then have a look at the example provided in Veins and the link I posted in the first comment. You now should have a good understanding of how Veins works. Hence, you can start implementing the techniques into `MyVeinsApp`. I suggest to use the original publications of those techniques, though.